# Using an angular expression with an ng-if directive

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to evaluate an angular expression in a ng-if?

For instance:

```
<div ng-if="itemData.contentTypeId = {{$root.res('resources', article_type_id')}}">
<!-- some content -->
<div>
```

also tried surrounding the expression in single quotes:

```
<div ng-if="itemData.contentTypeId = '{{$root.res('resources', article_type_id')}}'">
<!-- some content -->
<div>
```

and neither worked as expected.

Is this an issue with syntax or is this not possible?  If this is a syntax issue, how should the statement above be written?

Comment: have you tried with `==` instead of `=` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ng-if text IS an angular expression. Whatever string you write in there gets parsed by angular using `$scope.$eval()`. Any variables (including functions) that are used in the expression must be visible from the current $scope.
That means for this code to work, `$scope.$root` must be defined. Make sure it is, or you can't run the `res()` function, or else find another way.

`ng-if` evaluates the expression to a truthy or falsey value, so your `=` must be a comparison operator `==` or `===`.

```
<div ng-if="itemData.contentTypeId === $root.res('resources', article_type_id')">
```